# Django-Forms with json fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I am looking to accept json data in a form field and than validate it using some database operations. The data will mostly consist of an array of integers. So can you please help me as to how can i do so.

I have tried to google this but didn't get any decent answer. Please help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to take it as text input using `CharField`. And in the clean method of this field, you can validate it as per your requirement to check if input is valid.

Something like:

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
     jsonfield = forms.CharField(max_length=1024)

    def clean_jsonfield(self):
         jdata = self.cleaned_data['jsonfield']
         try:
             json_data = json.loads(jdata) #loads string as json
             #validate json_data
         except:
             raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid data in jsonfield")
         #if json data not valid:
            #raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid data in jsonfield")
         return jdata
```

You may also find a custom field for JSON data input.

Comment: Do you think making a custom field for json data will be a better option?? I also thought that but couldn't decide on it whether it was the best option or not?

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra, custom field would we good if you this is one of major functionalities. If this is one of then it may be little too much. Also, instead of writing new, look for any existing implementations.

Comment: @Rohan I got red zigzag line in PyCharm asking me import the module.

Comment: @Sarit for python 2.6+ use `import json`

Comment: what is the purpose of `json_data` then if we return `jdata` ?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny, just to validate the input

Comment: can I use `forms.JSONField` instead of  `forms.CharField` ?

Answer (score 11):

You can make forms with fields from JSON data with [that decision](https://github.com/abbasovalex/django-SplitJSONWidget-form)

Example:

**forms.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import forms
from splitjson.widgets import SplitJSONWidget


class testForm(forms.Form):
    attrs = {'class': 'special', 'size': '40'}
    data = forms.CharField(widget=SplitJSONWidget(attrs=attrs, debug=True))
```

**views.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from forms import testForm


def test_dict(request):
    json = {'a': 1,
            'b': 2,
            'c': 3,
            'd': 4}
    form = testForm(request.POST or None, initial={'data': json})
    if form.is_valid():
        # validate and save
        pass

    template = 'test_template.html'
    context = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
    return render_to_response(template, context)
```

**template.py**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Errors: 
        {% for field, error in form.errors.items %}
            <ul>
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            </ul>
        {% empty %}
            no errors 
        {% endfor %}
        <hr/>
        List of:
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p}}
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your Django model contains a JSON-field named, say `scope`, which either is a `django.contrib.postgres.forms.jsonb.JSONField` or a `jsonfield.fields.JSONField`, then simple rewrite your Django `ModelForm` as:

```
from django.form import fields
from entangled.forms import EntangledModelForm

class MyForm(EntangledModelForm):
    field1 = fields.CharField()
    ...
    class Meta:
        entangled_fields = {'scope': ['field1', ...]}
```

The class `EntangledModelForm` is a special variant of a Django `ModelForm` and must be imported from the 3rd-party library [django-entangled](https://pypi.org/project/django-entangled/).

This allows you to edit one or more JSON-fields with all the benefits, such as form validation and data cleaning, as provided by standard Django forms.

Answer (score 2):

Check [django-json-field](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field) which implements JSONField and associated form field.

Answer (score 2):

## Django 3.1 update

With the introduction of [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#jsonfield) all you need to do is:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    json_field = forms.JSONField()
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the most popular github repository with [JSONField](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield/) implementation.
You can install it with:

```
pip install jsonfield
```

For example, if you have a model

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    json_field = JSONField(default='', blank=True)
```

You can simply define a form with JSON validation

```
from django import forms
from jsonfield.fields import JSONFormField
from myapp import models


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        field_classes = {
            'json_field': JSONFormField,
        }
```

and use this form in your admin model

```
from django.contrib import admin

from myapp.forms import MyModelForm
from myapp.models import MyModel


@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

Answer (score 1):

`django.contrib.postgres` has a JSONField form field. Here is a link to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/). Field is represented by an HTML `<textarea>`.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.postgres.forms.jsonb import JSONField

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    metadata = JSONField()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**In simple:**

You do not want to change the default behavior of all your forms just use one function which will transform your request to objects.

```
form = myForm(jsonForm(request))

if form.is_valid():
   # Continue your stuffs
```

You can convert the request body to Python objects and pass to your form instead of passing the request directly.

```
def jsonForm(req):
    return json.loads(req.body.decode('utf-8'))
```