# How to receive json data using HTTP POST request in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, http-post, python-requests

I want to post some [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) using HTTP POST request and receive this data in Django.
I tried to use `request.POST['data']`, `request.raw_post_data`, `request.body` but none are working for me.

My views.py is:

```
import json
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
def main_page(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
            received_json_data=json.loads(request.POST['data'])
            #received_json_data=json.loads(request.body)
            return StreamingHttpResponse('it was post request: '+str(received_json_data))
    return StreamingHttpResponse('it was GET request')
```

I am posting JSON data using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module.

```
import requests  
import json
url = "http://localhost:8000"
data = {'data':[{'key1':'val1'}, {'key2':'val2'}]}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r=requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
r.text
```

`r.text` should print that message and posted data but I am not able to solve this simple problem. Please tell me how to collect posted data in Django?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where's my JSON data in my incoming Django request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208067/wheres-my-json-data-in-my-incoming-django-request)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You're confusing form-encoded and JSON data here. `request.POST['foo']` is for form-encoded data. You are posting raw JSON, so you should use `request.body`.

```
received_json_data=json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: request.body contains bytestring, whereas python3 json.loads expects a str thus you should decode first:
`data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
received_json_data = json.loads(data)`

Comment: But it said he tried `request.body`, how come it works for him now? I used `request.body` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 87):

For python3 you have to decode body first:

```
received_json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: This is no longer the case, as of Python 3.6 `JSON.loads()` accepts `bytes` and auto detects the UTF variant used to encode.

Answer (score -4):

Create a form with data as field of type `CharField` or `TextField` and validate the passed data. [Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626702/django-forms-with-json-fields)