# SNS Subscription Message from AWS in Python

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

The following is the `HTTP POST` message sent from `AWS` to confirm subscription to an `SNS` topic:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
x-amz-sns-message-type: SubscriptionConfirmation
x-amz-sns-message-id: 165545c9-2a5c-472c-8df2-7ff2be2b3b1b
x-amz-sns-topic-arn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic
Content-Length: 1336
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Host: myhost.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent

{
  "Type" : "SubscriptionConfirmation",
  "MessageId" : "165545c9-2a5c-472c-8df2-7ff2be2b3b1b",
  "Token" : "2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e241d09c805a5a57b30d712f794cc5f6a988666d92768dd60a747ba6f3beb71854e285d6ad02428b09ceece29417f1f02d609c582afbacc99c583a916b9981dd2728f4ae6fdb82efd087cc3b7849e05798d2d2785c03b0879594eeac82c01f235d0e717736",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic",
  "Message" : "You have chosen to subscribe to the topic arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic.\nTo confirm the subscription, visit the SubscribeURL included in this message.",
  "SubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=ConfirmSubscription&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic&Token=2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e241d09c805a5a57b30d712f794cc5f6a988666d92768dd60a747ba6f3beb71854e285d6ad02428b09ceece29417f1f02d609c582afbacc99c583a916b9981dd2728f4ae6fdb82efd087cc3b7849e05798d2d2785c03b0879594eeac82c01f235d0e717736",
  "Timestamp" : "2012-04-26T20:45:04.751Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "EXAMPLEpH+DcEwjAPg8O9mY8dReBSwksfg2S7WKQcikcNKWLQjwu6A4VbeS0QHVCkhRS7fUQvi2egU3N858fiTDN6bkkOxYDVrY0Ad8L10Hs3zH81mtnPk5uvvolIC1CXGu43obcgFxeL3khZl8IKvO61GWB6jI9b5+gLPoBc1Q=",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem"
  }
```

In Python, how do I access the `JSON` seen at the bottom of the message using the request?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068576/how-to-receive-json-data-using-http-post-request-in-django-1-6) what you are looking for? Basically just json.loads(request.body)?

Comment: Yes, of course... I'm an idiot. It was something completely different causing an error when I tested this the first time. Thanks!