# How to get all dict data

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am using Python 2.7.11 and Django 1.10.2. How do I get JSON data in Django views. I have tried for two days but I only get only **List** data.

This is my example, I need the "**parent**" data.

```
 [
   {
    "url": "",
    "category_image": [],
    "price_rule": null,
    "parent": {
      "id": 12,
      "category_image": [],
      ........
    },
    "name": "cat2",
    "slug": "cat2",
    .........
  },
]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a question and answer website, but there is no question here.

Comment: You need to show what you tried, the output you want,  what you got instead, and any errors.

Comment: you should look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068576/how-to-receive-json-data-using-http-post-request-in-django-1-6

Answer (score 0):

If you want get **parent** data, you can do something like this:

```
    id = list_data[0]['parent']['id']
```

This should return 12. If you want category_image, you can try:

```
    category = list_data[0]['parent']['category_image']
```

If i understand your question correctly, this is your answer.

Comment: Thanku sir. i will checking it.