# Why request body in JSON is not mentioned as acceptable in Django Rest Documentation?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have written backend using Django Rest Framework. I am sure that `json` is working properly, however in the documentation I have only mentioned in create methods `Request Body - The request body should be a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoded object, containing the following items.` Does anyone have an idea why there is no information about json format? It seems to me that it should be something like this `Body - The request body should be a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "application/json"`
[image]

Comment: This is something you should raise on the project's github instead of here.

Comment: @JonClements why?

Comment: The people best suited are the developers as to why it says that... and if it's an omission then it'd be best they correct it in the codebase, no? So unless one of the developers comes along and replies to this post, the best you're gong to get is guesses... So you might as well raise it directly with the people that definitely know and can change it if needs be...

Comment: @Wahtdbogh If you'd like to accept JSON requests, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24068576/1925257).

Comment: @xyres but my backend accepts JSON requests. Everything works properly. The only problem is that there is not generated information about it in Django Documentation.  There is only mentioned "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". So the user will not be informed that he can also send data in json.