# JSONDecodeError, when use json.loads in Django

Tags: json, django, django-views

JSONDecodeError, when use json.loads in Django.

POST data

> (b'csrfmiddlewaretoken=ikpUI4vMMbYivTby6FUkXRGNXisF6Cgq5eRnYvqoxRoyfAkwiP5GlsBj'
>   b'jVlh3Va4&pergunta%5B1%5D%5Bitem%5D%5B1%5D=&pergunta%5B1%5D%5Bitem%5D%5B2%5D='
>   b'&pergunta%5B2%5D%5Bitem%5D%5B3%5D=&pergunta%5B2%5D%5Bitem%5D%5B4%5D=&pergunt'
>   b'a%5B2%5D%5Bitem%5D%5B5%5D=&pergunta%5B2%5D%5Bitem%5D%5B6%5D=')

```
def post(self, request):

    data = json.loads(request.body)
    pprint(data)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Output Error

> JSONDecodeError at /
>
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/rma/ Django
>   Version:  1.11.7 Exception Type:  JSONDecodeError Exception Value:
>   Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) Exception
>   Location: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py
>   in raw_decode, line 357 Python
>   Executable:   /Users/marcelowanderley/Python-Compare/bin/python Python
>   Version:  3.6.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to parse \`request.body\` from POST in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780060/trying-to-parse-request-body-from-post-in-django)

Comment: Hi, Satendra. Is different. My code is generating an error in executing JSON DECODER. Even then I tried to use the format of this post, without success the same error is shown. Thank you.

Comment: What is the content of `request.body`?

Comment: Hi, Alasdair. A POST form simple. Thank you.

Comment: looks like [For python3 you have to decode body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35087348/8060120)

Comment: Hi Bear. Same error. Thank you

Comment: Resolved with request.POST.dict() . thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

as @marcelo.delta said and for me worked also...

request.POST.dict()