# Django 2 Login Registration

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm Prety new in Django. After a few google search, I find full CRUD and I know how to handle that. But in User registration, I fell some problem all over the online every one uses Form.py to handle registration form but I don't want to use Form.py I like to customize it.

but the problem is when I use auth for login then Django auth says it's a wrong password

I use

```
authenticate(email=email,password=password)
```

for login check

Is anyone please explain custom login registration **without using Form.py** with some example.

Here is my View.py Code

```
def loginCheck(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username'),
        password = request.POST.get('password'),
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:

            return HttpResponse('Find User')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Not Find User")
```

and my User Registration Code

```
def registration(request):
    checkData = AuthUser.objects.filter(email=request.POST.get('email'))
    if not checkData:
        User.objects.create_user(
            username=request.POST.get('username'),
            email=request.POST.get('email'),
            password=(request.POST.get('password')),
        )
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'User Saved Successfully')
        return redirect('loginView')
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Email Already Exists')
        return redirect('loginView')
```

My Login code return *Not Find User*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this minimal example. In this, you can create User and log in through API.

```
import json
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


class UserRegisterView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({"message": "METHOD NOT ALLOWED"})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        json_body = json.loads(request.body)
        username = json_body.get('username')
        password = json_body.get('password')
        email = json_body.get('email')
        is_staff = json_body.get('is_staff', False)
        is_superuser = json_body.get('is_superuser', False)
        User.objects.create_user(
            username=username, email=email,
            password=password, is_staff=is_staff,
            is_superuser=is_superuser
        )
        return JsonResponse({"message": "User created"})


class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({"message": "METHOD NOT ALLOWED"})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        input data format:

        {
        "username" : "my username",
        "password":"mysecret123@"
        }

        '''
        json_body = json.loads(request.body)
        username = json_body.get('username')
        password = json_body.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return JsonResponse({"message": "login success"})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "login failed"})
```

Why I parsed **`request.body`** ? 
    [How to receive json data using HTTP POST request in DJANGO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068576/how-to-receive-json-data-using-http-post-request-in-django-1-6)

**Reference:**
[How to authenticate user in DJANGO](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) (official-doc)

**UPDAYE-1**
updated view as per the request,checking sufficent data in POST method (bold code)

```
def loginCheck(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.POST and 'password' in request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username'),
        password = request.POST.get('password'),
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:

            return HttpResponse('Find User')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Not Find User")
    return HttpResponse("POST data wrong")
```

Comment: @Antu I updated the answer with few references, check those too , if you want

Comment: Hi @jerin I edit my question would you please check this?

Comment: try to print `username` and `password` before authenticate. CHeck those values

Comment: anyway, I updated the answer. Please look into bolded text

Comment: I check username and password before **authenticate** its return data no problem with that but when I try to authenticate and find user
`user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`
it's getting None,  I also try to find the only username it's not getting that. Sir would you please run my code? I'm really in a serious problem with this.

Comment: Can you share that project?

Comment: Sure, Sir, it's just a simple login registration system before starting my main project I'm working on it. how can I share with you this?

Comment: github or something similar...dont forget to add `requirements.txt` file

Comment: remove ending comma in `username = request.POST.get('username'),` and `password = request.POST.get('password'),` .

Comment: If you put comma, python consider it as `tupple` rather than string

Comment: Thank You so much sir I understand what is wrong with my code thank you

Comment: look at this [line](https://github.com/Antu7/TestRepo/blob/master/login/views.py#L33), remove the comma from line 33 and 34

Answer (score 1):

If you want to your own registration process, you must use set_password function for saving password.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.get_or_create(username='john')
user.set_password('new password')
user.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how do I authenticate password for login? 
`auth.authenticate(email=email,password=password)`
is this ok for this?

Comment: After django receive password, it must hash that first, then store it on db. so we must use set_password. then you can use  auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

Comment: but with username, not email. if you want to use email, you must customize User model