# Django parameter stops printing when it reaches the first question mark symbol

Tags: python, django, url-parameters

I have been learning the weird set-ups of Django! Its very good for web development!

I have the following view inside views.py:

```
def callerview(request,paramm):
  text="this is what was sent : %s"%paramm
   return HttpResponse(text)
```

the url for this this view at urls.py is as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('callerview/<str:paramm>/', views.callerview, name='callerview'),
]
```

Now, I am sending a word problem to it as the 'paramm'. It works and prints the word problem at localhost. But if the word problem has a question mark it stops printing when it gets to the first ? .

**so if the url looks like**:  callerview/why are roses red? why is the sky blue?
Then, in the localhost output i will get:  why are roses red **AND** no more!

I need to be able to get all the symbols and letters in the word problem! in order to send to OpenAi assistants API.

Any advice on how I can keep the ? symbol in the printout of the word problem?

Comment: Because [the question mark is reserved in HTTP URLs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-3.3). It represents the start of query parameters in HTTP URLs.

Comment: It usually doesn't make sense to use user query / inputs as part of the URL path, it should either be send as part of the query string or in the request body. In your case you should be sending that data as the request body in a POST request (Calling the OpenAI API is something that would incur you cost, and also it generates a response instead of just returning something existing).

Comment: It is perfectly fine if the URL parameter is an `str`. But if the `str` happens to be a question, then url encoding should suffice.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ok do you know how can I add the paramm as the content in the call to the OpenAi assistant. I was trying to set the content=text . I am referring to this code: message = client.beta.threads.messages.create( thread_id=thread.id,role="user",
            content=text)

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon that string is not some existing resource which they are creating a URL for but rather a user submitted input. To put it in simple terms they are using the URL path as a form and submitting data as part of it. Although it is possible to do this it is _semantically wrong_. The correct thing to do is to use query strings (if it should be a GET request) or to send it as part of the request body.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am sending this word problems via android app using Volley Network Library. From what I understand I need to send the word problem as a param. I still need to know why in the message creation of the OpenAi assistants api the content key:value pair key = content  is not accepting text as value!

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I gave a general answer. To be specific for the OP given the scenario, a `POST` request is more appropriate considering the fact that OpenAI assistant could also be communicated with using images. Giving room for that to your users is the best way to go. To summarize, do not use a `GET` request but a `POST` request.

Comment: @ChrisK0043 that's a separate question. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you don't find any suitable existing ones.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Ok I will try a post request with one single POST parameter. Now, how will I be able to get the POST parameter and turn it to a string? Say I give the key:value as  problem: what is the square root of 225 . Using Django how can I just get the value not the key?

Comment: @ChrisK0043 see: [How to get POST request values in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/how-to-get-post-request-values-in-django) or [How to receive json data using HTTP POST request in Django 1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068576/how-to-receive-json-data-using-http-post-request-in-django-1-6)

Comment: There you have it. @AbdulAzizBarkat has answered that. There’s more resources in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[The question mark is reserved in HTTP URLs. <sup>[RFC 1738]</sup>](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-3.3) It represents the start of query parameters in HTTP URLs.

In your case, the URL parameter ends where the symbol ***?*** is found and the query parameters begin from there. Django simply follows the [URL specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738).

Comment: ok. So how can I force the url param to keep the '?' is there a way? I need the param to include all the grammatical symbols. The param is supposed to be a word problem? Or maybe I just format the param before its sent on the URL request

Comment: Use URLEncoding to encode reserved keywords. [The code for `?` is `%3F` in hex encoding](https://www.ascii-code.com/63).

Comment: @ChrisK0043 you should not be sending that information as part of the URL at all. See my comment on the question.